# Moving an object in a specific way

Tags: animation, fcurves

Is it possible to show an f-curve in an animation to show how the object moves as the frames progress? I want to show how the object moves in the animation as well as show it's position on a curve since my displacement is really small.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [Calculate Motion Paths](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/keyframes/visualization.html) help?

Comment: It seems like something valid to do but it's displayed in the same scene as the animation itself. I was thinking more along the lines of a tennis ball bounces in a damped manner. This would be shown as the animation itself but I wanted to have the path that it followed be displayed separately as in a graph with a dot representing the ball's motion as it damps out over time.

Comment: You can't have multiple screens and record the whole thing with Bandicam or similar?  Or record separate screens and  overlay one on the other later?